# Result object used to throw the exception and catching from view model is not working

Tags: android, kotlin

**Action.kt**

```
abstract class Action<in Input, out Output> {
    protected abstract suspend fun action(input: Input): Output

    protected open fun dispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO

    suspend operator fun invoke(input: Input): Output = withContext(dispatcher()) {
        action(input)
    }
}
```

**IsNewDataToBeFetchedFromServerUseCase.kt**

```
class IsNewDataToBeFetchedFromServerUseCase @Inject constructor(
    @IoDispatcher private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
) : Action<Unit, Result<Boolean>>() {
    
    override suspend fun action(input: Unit): Result<Boolean> = withContext(context = dispatcher) {
        return@withContext Result.failure(Exception("Message"))
    }
    
}
```

**How I am using the usecase in view model** ---> Here in the vew model I am not able to catch exception even if the usecase throws exception

```
useCases.isNewDataToBeFetchedFromServerUseCase.invoke(Unit).onSuccess {
                println("")
            }.onFailure {
                println(it.message)
            }
```

Comment: You call it in viewmodelscope.launch, right?

Comment: @ΓDΛ ... Yes I am able to call it and it works but .... if the use case throws an exception ... In the ViewModel the onFailure is not able to catch exception as shown

Comment: can you try this. 

viewModelScope.launch {
    useCases.isNewDataToBeFetchedFromServerUseCase.invoke(Unit).fold(
        onSuccess = {
            println("")
        },
        onFailure = {
            println(it.message)
        }
    )
}